# I tried to update from 13.04 to 13.10. Got the "Could not calculate the upgrade" error

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I ran

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

Here is what I got

```
Broken libpam-systemd:i386 Conflicts on libpam-xdg-support [ i386 ] < 0.2-0ubuntu2 > ( universe/admin )

Broken iputils-ping:i386 Depends on libgnutls-openssl27 [ i386 ] < none -> 2.12.23-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )

Broken ubuntu-standard:i386 Depends on dnsutils [ i386 ] < none -> 1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2 > ( net )`
```

I would appreciate your help in resolving this error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63885-An-unresolvable-problem-occurred-while-calculating-the-upgrade) worked for me

```
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a common issue I've seen and have experienced myself. Here is your solution:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bak; sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bak /etc/apt/sources.list.d; sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop -y
```

This will backup your PPAs by moving them so they don't interfere with the upgrade, upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10, then put your PPAs back and update them to Saucy, and finally attempt to install PPA packages for Saucy. Some of your PPAs may not support Saucy yet, however.

Be sure to carefully watch the output for any issues.

Comment: That will kill the installation. Murphy says that is most likely that you will mess up your installation (mimicking Debian upgrade method) that you successfully upgrade.

Comment: See this http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7516/169736

Comment: Braiam, you clearly don't know what you are talking about. it will not 'kill the installation'. To make such statements is a clear indicator that you know absolutely nothing about this subject. I advise you to look into the documentation of how 'do-release-upgrade' works.