# Ubuntu upgrade fails from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

Ubuntu upgrade fails with following lines:

```
Calculating the changes
Calculating the changes
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

in the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

Broken libwayland-client0:amd64 Conflicts on libwayland0 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.5-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.1.0)
Broken libunity9:amd64 Breaks on unity-common [ amd64 ] < 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 7.1.2)
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on ghostscript-cups [ amd64 ] < 9.07~dfsg2-0ubuntu3.1 > ( text )
Broken libpam-systemd:amd64 Conflicts on libpam-xdg-support [ amd64 ] < 0.2-0ubuntu2 > ( admin )
Broken libharfbuzz0a:amd64 Breaks on libharfbuzz0 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.13-1 > ( libs )
Broken libharfbuzz0a:amd64 Breaks on libharfbuzz0 [ i386 ] < 0.9.13-1 > ( libs )
Broken libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-common [ amd64 ] < 6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 7.0.7)
Broken libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-common [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 7.0.7)
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Conflicts on account-plugin-generic-oauth [ amd64 ] < 0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1 > ( gnome ) (< 0.10bzr13.04.30)
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Breaks on account-plugin-generic-oauth [ amd64 ] < 0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1 > ( gnome ) (< 0.10bzr13.04.30)
Broken python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:amd64 Breaks on libpackagekit-glib2-14 [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-3ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (<= 0.7.6-4)
Broken libsnmp30:amd64 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ amd64 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.7ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken unity-gtk2-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk [ amd64 ] < 12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libqscintilla2-l10n:amd64 Breaks on libqscintilla2-translations [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken unity-gtk3-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk3 [ amd64 ] < 12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken activity-log-manager:amd64 Conflicts on activity-log-manager-common [ amd64 ] < 0.9.4-0ubuntu6.2 > ( utils )
Broken libgtksourceview-3.0-0:amd64 Depends on libgtksourceview-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.7)
Broken libunity-core-6.0-5:amd64 Depends on unity-services [ amd64 ] < 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 -> 7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1)
Broken libbamf3-1:amd64 Depends on bamfdaemon [ amd64 ] < 0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 -> 0.5.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1)
Broken geany-plugin-gdb:amd64 Depends on geany-plugins-common [ amd64 ] < 0.21.1.dfsg-4 -> 1.23+dfsg-3 > ( universe/devel ) (= 0.21.1.dfsg-4)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libxfixes3:amd64 Breaks on xserver-xorg-core [ amd64 ] < 2:1.13.4~git20130508+server-1.13-branch.10c42f57-0ubuntu0ricotz~raring -> 2:1.14.3-3ubuntu2 > ( x11 ) (< 2:1.14)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-cirrus:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.1.99+git20130730.6a278369-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring -> 1:7.2.0-0ubuntu10 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.1.99+git20130730.6a278369-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring -> 1:7.2.0-0ubuntu10 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-cirrus [ amd64 ] < 1:1.5.2+git20130108.e2bf5b25-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.904+git20131009.b9ad5b62-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~raring > ( x11 )
```

Please help me to fix problem...

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/361716/i-tried-to-update-from-13-04-to-13-10-got-the-could-not-calculate-the-upgrade/362784

Comment: A clean install via CD/DVD or USB stick would perhaps clear up the difficulty you are encountering.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. Removing the package called xserver-xorg-video-nouveau allows you to upgrade. You can always reinstall the package thereafter if you require it